# Saving files in folder using Ionic 4 and Electron Desktop

Tags: angular, electron, ionic4, desktop-application

I would like to save a file from my Ionic 4 app to a folder using background service. I’ve built a desktop app using Electron for Windows.

Is there any way we can save files in Desktop using Ionic 4 Electron build?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Capacitor to build the desktop app using Ionic and Electron...
Some info on getting started here: https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/electron
Also I guess to save the file you'd use FileSystem plugin: https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/filesystem

Comment: I've already built electron desktop app using ionic cordova....I think native file system apis are for Android/IOS devices only....Is there anyway I can save files in desktop using ionic cordova